# How to use loops with Mata

Tags: stata

I want to implement a one-line command within a `for` loop in Mata. However, I get an error even with the most simple commands. Take the simple command to display a value:

```
mata: i = 2
mata: i^2
. 4
```

But if I try to put this squared variable command into a loop, thus:

```
mata: for (i=1; i<=3; i++) { i^2 }
```

I get the following result:

```
invalid expression
r(3000);
```

when I would expect to see something like:

```
. 1
. 4
. 9
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual for **[M2] for** states one-liners have no braces: `for (exp1; exp2; exp3) stmt`.

```
clear all
set more off

mata: for (i=1; i<=3; i++) i^2 

// invoke Mata mode
mata

for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    i^2 
}

// end Mata mode
end
```

*stmt* stands for statement.

Comment: Ok, that works. BUT: the mata documentation explicitly includes curly-brace-delimited blocks in describing for (and other) loops. What am I not understanding about, for example, the second syntax form here: in `help m2_for`?

Comment: The one-liner syntax can be used simply with `mata:` prefixed. The block syntax you can use surrounding with `mata` (or `mata:`) and `end`. The former takes no braces, the latter does. I've added a bit of code. See **[M1]
Introduction and advice**.

Comment: I often use Mata for one-line calculations and I often use Mata to write more substantial Stata-Mata programs with Mata functions with looping, etc., etc.. There is an intermediate style but it's hard to see why it would be optimal for any task. Otherwise put, you're asking a question about language rules, which is fine, but the context in which you think this is a good thing to do is lacking.